# Filtrar usando grep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

Tengo el siguiente dataset:

```
%mpg, cylinders, displacement, horsepower, weight, acceleration, model year, origin, car name
18.0, 8, 307.0, 130.0, 3504., 12.0, 70, 1, "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
24.0, 4, 133.0, 95.00, 2372., 15.0, 70, 2, "toyota corona mark ii"
16.0, 4, 122.0, 70.00, 1800., 14.0, 70, 3, "lala"
```

Estoy haciendo un script para que me sustituya los valores de la columna origin por su procedencia. Por ejemplo, si es 1 = USA, si es 2 = Europe y si es 3 = Asia. Después de esto, filtro la líneas usando `grep` por la procedencia de interés. En mi caso, USA. A continuación, el script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}
{
#Reemplazo valores
if($8==1) $8=="USA";
if($8==2) $8=="Europe";
if($8==3) $8=="Asia";
#Filtramos por USA
registros = grep -E ".*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,USA,.*"
print $registros
}
```

Sin embargo, no estoy obteniendo ningún registro.

Comment: es que estás llamando a "grep" desde un script de Awk, cosa que no puede hacerse. ¿Por qué no usas Awk también para filtrar? Al fin y al cabo, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Quieres mostrar las líneas cuyo destino sea USA? En tal caso, puedes hacer un pipe `| awk -F, '$8 == "USA"'`.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tanto tienes un *typo* al momento de la asignación (utilizas `==` en lugar de `=`) de cada variable, y además estás haciendo una cosa extraña con `grep` dentro de `awk`.

Refactoricé tu código quedando de esta manera:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}
{
    if($8 == 1)
        $8="USA"
    else if($8 == 2)
        $8="Europe"
    else if($8 == 3)
        $8="Asia";
    print $0
}
```

Si le llamamos a tu archivo awk *main.awk* y a tu dataset *dataset*, puedes correrlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$ awk -f ./main.awk dataset
%mpg, cylinders, displacement, horsepower, weight, acceleration, model year, origin, car name
18.0, 8, 307.0, 130.0, 3504., 12.0, 70,USA, "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
24.0, 4, 133.0, 95.00, 2372., 15.0, 70,Europe, "toyota corona mark ii"
16.0, 4, 122.0, 70.00, 1800., 14.0, 70,Asia, "lala"
```

[Aquí](https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/stackoverflow_answers/-/tree/master/bash/454448) tienes un repositorio con el ejemplo.